# Multiple errors import Oracle 12c DB impdb

Tags: oracle, impdp

I am a custom developer and I need to restore an Oracle DB and receiving multiple errors during the import. Very new to oracle, thanks in advance

System has been granted read/write on dump directory

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY dpump_dirOW AS 'E:\Dump';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY dpump_dirOW TO SYSTEM;

impdp system/system@oracle1 FULL=Y DIRECTORY=dpump_dirOW DUMPFILE=full_EDML48T1_export_121019.dmp LOGFILE=5expdp_Merit121619.log exclude=table_statistics;
```

Errors from log file

```
;;; 
Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Dec 18 08:37:30 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
import done in AL32UTF8 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
Warning: possible data loss in character set conversions
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  system/********@oracle1 FULL=Y DIRECTORY=dpump_dirOW DUMPFILE=full_EDML48T1_export_121019.dmp LOGFILE=4expdp_Merit121619.log 
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PRE_SYSTEM_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PRE_INSTANCE_IMPCALLOUT/MARKER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TABLESPACE
ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE:"TOOLS" failed to create with error:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/oradata/EDML48T1/tools03.dbf'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.

Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLESPACE "TOOLS" DATAFILE '/oradata/EDML48T1/tools03.dbf' SIZE 805306368 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 104857600 MAXSIZE 32767M,'/oradata/EDML48T1/tools01.dbf' SIZE 805306368 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 104857600 MAXSIZE 32767M,'/oradata/EDML48T1/tools02.dbf' SIZE 805306368 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 104857600 MAXSIZE 32767M LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192 EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS  SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE:"EDMDATA4" failed to create with error:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/oradata/EDML48T1/edmdata401.dbf'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.

Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLESPACE "EDMDATA4" DATAFILE '/oradata/EDML48T1/edmdata401.dbf' SIZE 805306368 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 104857600 MAXSIZE 32767M,'/oradata/EDML48T1/edmdata402.dbf' SIZE 805306368 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 104857600 MAXSIZE 32767M,'/oradata/EDML48T1/edmdata403.dbf' SIZE 805306368 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 104857600 MAXSIZE 32767M LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192 EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS  SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE:"EDMHIST1" failed to create with error:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/oradata/EDML48T1/edmhist103.dbf'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.
```

And on and on....

Comment: Well, do you have `/oradata/EDML48T1`? Can Oracle access it?

Comment: I did manually create the EDML48T1 folder in, C:\O12Install\oradata\EDML48T1, not sure now to test if Oracle can access it

Comment: `ls -l`, `chown`, `chmod`. Oracle directories should be owned by the Oracle user ID, and probably not accessible by any other ID.

Comment: Looks like you want to import a dump made from a database running on Linux into a database running on Windows. Obviously, the path names cannot match (`/oradata/EDML48T1` is **NOT** the same as `C:\O12Install\oradata\EDML48T1`). You could try to manually create the tablespaces in your new database, then run the import again.